# Error relocating - symbol not found - building docker-fpm-alpine image

Tags: docker

Trying to create an image (from a working one) I got this error, been googling the solution but couldn't find a proper one, I asume something's wrong with libraries. Don't fully understand what "Error relocating symbol not found" means, the previous steps ran successfully, this is the error output:

```
    Executing busybox-1.28.4-r1.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20171114-r3.trigger
OK: 142 MiB in 67 packages
+ mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext
+ wget https://pecl.php.net/get/memcached
Error relocating /lib/libssl.so.45: explicit_bzero: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libssl.so.45: getentropy: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libcrypto.so.43: explicit_bzero: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libcrypto.so.43: getentropy: symbol not found
Removing intermediate container e3b8422b922a
The command '/bin/sh -c set -xe && apk add --no-cache py-setuptools git wget bash py-setuptools zlib-dev libpng-dev freetype-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libmcrypt-dev libmemcached-dev icu-dev libxml2-dev && apk add --no-cache libressl-dev cyrus-sasl-dev --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/ rabbitmq-c-dev gnu-libiconv --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted && mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext && wget https://pecl.php.net/get/memcached && tar -xf memcached && rm memcached && mv memcached-* /usr/src/php/ext/memcached && wget https://pecl.php.net/get/redis && tar -xf redis && rm redis && mv redis-* /usr/src/php/ext/redis && wget https://pecl.php.net/get/amqp && tar -xf amqp && rm amqp && mv amqp-* /usr/src/php/ext/amqp && wget https://pecl.php.net/get/igbinary && tar -xf igbinary && rm igbinary && mv igbinary-* /usr/src/php/ext/igbinary && wget https://pecl.php.net/get/apcu && tar -xf apcu && rm apcu && mv apcu-* /usr/src/php/ext/apcu && wget https://pecl.php.net/get/mcrypt && tar -xf mcrypt && rm mcrypt && mv mcrypt-* /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt && git clone --recursive --depth=1 https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-snappy.git && mv php-ext-snappy /usr/src/php/ext/snappy && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql opcache zip pcntl mcrypt iconv soap intl xml amqp igbinary redis snappy apcu && docker-php-ext-configure memcached --enable-memcached-igbinary --disable-memcached-sasl && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && docker-php-ext-install gd memcached && echo 'extension = "apcu.so"' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-apcu.ini && echo 'apc.shm_size = 256M' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-apcu.ini' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was changing:

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```

to

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

within the `/etc/apk/repositories` file and then running `apk update && apk upgrade`.

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: The path, instead of edge/main had to go for edge/testing.

Comment: The path? How does the path concept relate to the terminology in the question?

Comment: @PimHeijden Changing the url path in `/etc/apk/repositories` file

Comment: in the image? @MuhammetMadraimov

Comment: Yes @PimHeijden

Comment: According to number of the voites to the answer: only 2 people real understand what is going. :)

Answer (score 13):

There are well-documented incompatibilities between the minimal (musl) system C library (`libc.so`) that ships with Alpine Linux and the bigger (GNU) libc that ships with more typical Linux distributions.  Those error messages hint that you're tripping over something like that.

If you're installing 142 MB of development packages you're not really building a "tiny" Docker image, and the easiest fix is to change your image to be based on `ubuntu:18.04` instead of the Alpine base it's presumably using now.  Your final image will wind up being more like 400 MB than like 200 MB, but it's unlikely you'll notice any practical differences.

Comment: Thanks, but we use this image a lot, so, we'll double the disk space use at the cluster if we change to ubuntu:xxxxx. 
I fixed changing http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/ to http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/

Comment: Launching additional containers off of the same image doesn't require any additional disk space.

Comment: How is the size of the image relevant? Are you generally discouraging using Alpine?

Comment: No, I was mistaken there on the disk usage by images.

Comment: this `apk upgrade musl` worked for me.